# VBA finding any value between two others

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to complete a small VBA project in Excel, the purpose is to allow me to filter data more easily than using the built in filter/search options. Essentially I have a form with some user inputs relating to the data headers. I have an input for a tolerance band on the value being searched for, for example the input is: Header name; Nominal search value; tolerance. It will then find all rows of data that are within that tolerance.

The code which I am hoping to loop in order to run through and copy each row to a new sheet is below. I want to set the range "fc" to be equal to the first found cell that is between ssMin and ssMax. Am I better off using an If block?

```
Private Function searchCells(ifc)
    Dim ss As Integer
    Dim fc As Range
    Dim ssMax As Integer
    Dim ssMin As Integer

    ss = lstboxChannelList.List(ifc, 1)
    ssMax = ss + lstboxChannelList.List(ifc, 2)
    ssMin = ss - lstboxChannelList.List(ifc, 2)

    Set fc = Cells.Find(What:=(ssMin <= ssMax), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    fc.Select

    End Function
```

Comment: Your `What:=(ssMin <= ssMax)` is almost certainly equivalent to `What:=True` (assuming that `ssMin` is less than or equal to `ssMax`), so that approach won't work.  Yes, you will be better off looping through the data using a loop and testing each individual cell to see whether it meets the criteria.  (If it was just a single column you were searching, it **might** be possible to do it using just `Index` and `Match` operations but, because your data is anywhere within the entire worksheet, I don't think that will be possible for you.)

Comment: You could also consider taking the input from the user form and using that as criteria for Excel's Simple or Advanced filter.  MIght be faster than looping through all the cells, and could still be done using VBA to simplify setting up the criteria.  With the Advanced Filter, you could use the `CopyTo` parameter.  With the Simple Filter, you would copy the visible cells after filtering.

Comment: Thanks both, I will try those approaches today to see how I get on and hopefully post an answer once I have it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for the comments, I had a play around today but couldn't get the advanced filter to do what I was wanting. Settled with this little if statement which makes me wonder why I bothered with the .find in the first place. "fr" is a range which is selected in the previous function that is passed through, I wasn't sure if it was tidier to assign this as a range in the place it is selected but I'm a little confused how I pass it from the function back to the sub then back to another function but this method seems to work. Thanks again to those that commented!

```
Private Function searchCells(ifc)
Dim ss As Integer
Dim fc As Range
Dim ssMax As Integer
Dim ssMin As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim fr As Range

ss = lstboxChannelList.List(ifc, 1)
ssMax = ss + lstboxChannelList.List(ifc, 2)
ssMin = ss - lstboxChannelList.List(ifc, 2)


Set fr = Selection
For Each cell In fr

    If cell.Value < ssMax And cell.Value > ssMin Then
        cell.Select
        'More code to come here
        'MsgBox ("found one!")

    End If

Next cell

End Function
```